# WPF Converter, Convertback loses data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress

I've been stuck on the following problem now already for a while, without finding a solution for it.
I have a WPF application in which we show a grid in which every cell contains an object of a custom type `DoubleInputCell`. This object contains its *value, an id, a tooltip, and some more settings*.

To obtain the value out of this object we have a converter as following:

```
public class DoubleCellValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as DoubleInputCell)?.Value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new DoubleInputCell() { Value = double.Parse(value.ToString()), State = new ManualState() };
    }
}
```

This works correctly in both directions. **However**, when a value has changed I also have to change the tooltip from inside the **ViewModel** to be something like "Previous input: xxx". This has to happen in the ViewModel due to the need for these values being stored for when they chang the selection, so the grid gets filled with other data. When going back, this tooltip has to be used instead of the default.

At this moment my XAML looks like the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DoubleCellTemplate">
   <Grid>
      <dxe:TextEdit Name="PART_Editor" 
                    MaskType="Numeric"
                    FontSize="10"
                    DisplayFormatString="f3"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                    ToolTip="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource DoubleCellToolTipConverter}}"
                    EditValue="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource DoubleCellValueConverter}}"/>
     <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="2" />
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

But now due to the converter not receiving the complete object back, and thus not being able to set the tooltip and other properties, these values get lost. Which results in **always** having an empty tooltip after the first change of the cell value.

I have also tried to not use a converter and just throw an event when the value gets changed in the object itself. However the object never entered the **set** state anymore, thus not being able to throw this event.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can overcome this problem?

**EDIT**

This is the `DoubleInputCell` class

```
public class DoubleInputCell : ICell, IValue<double?>
{
    public string CellId { get; set; }
    public double? Value { get; set; }
    public IState State { get; set; } = new ManualState();
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; } = false;
    public string MaskType { get; set; } = "Numeric";
    public string Mask { get; set; } = "f3";
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You bind the `ToolTip` and `EditValue` target properties to the same source property...what property do you expect to get set to the value that the converter returns? Bind `ToolTip` to `Value.ToolTip` and `EditValue` to `Value.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

You bind the `ToolTip` and `EditValue` target properties to the same source property...what property do you expect to get set to the value that the converter returns?

Why don't you Bind `ToolTip` to `Value.ToolTip` and `EditValue` to `Value.Value`?:

```
ToolTip="{Binding Value.ToolTip}"
EditValue="{Binding Value.Value}"
```

If you want to change the `ToolTip` property based on the `Value` property, you could do this in the setter of the latter without using a converter in the view.

Comment: When you bind to the Value.Value directly no EditValueChanged event will be thrown by the devExpress control (or in general in WPF, cannot say that). That is why we have the converter and this one takes out the value.
As said, it displays all data correctly. It is only that I need to be able to update the whole cell and not just what happens inside the convertback

Comment: Thrown or raised? The event should be raised when the value is actually changed, shouldn't it?

Comment: Raised, my apologies, no it does not. Hereby the answer of DevExpress at the time I had also problems due to the usage of `Value.Value``
GridControl raises the CellValueChanging and CellValueChanged events only for cells that use its native data binding mechanism. You can assign EditSettings to a column or put a BaseEdit descendant named "PART_Editor" in CellTemplate to use it. As you bind your editors in CellTemplate manually, it is expected to see that these events are not raised.

Comment: You can still not bind two target properties to one source property without losing values.

Comment: you were correct, this approach would never work correctly. I have posted the correct solution as an answer.

Comment: @svenQ: Why didn't you accept my answer instead of addning your own nearly identical one...?

Comment: because yours is wrong and would NEVER work due to the lack of the Converter on the value. The value would always get lost in this case

Comment: @svenQ: If that's the case, there is something wrong with the control.

Answer (score -1):

Have found the correct solution to this problem. Actually it was self-explanatory, but since I had tried that approach before and it didn't function, I went into the wrong direction.

I should not make use of the converter for the ToolTip and just bind directly to the property itself as mm8 said.

```
ToolTip="{Binding Value.ToolTip}"
```

Then In my model I should have raised the `OnPropertyChanged` event for the ToolTip when its value changed.